# How to scale down right column in grid to max. 100% of left column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, height

I have two columns side by side in a bootstrap grid. I need to force the second column not to be higher than the first one. I know how to force the second column to get full height in dependance of the first column by using widespread method of display: table.
But how to manage the other way round? I prefer a solution using css, no js if possible.
The first one contains a responsive image, second one contains text.
If the text would need more space than the image, text should scroll.

```
<div class="row">       
<div class="col-xs-6 first">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="image/example.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 second">
    <p>
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check this example

If you want to do height adjustment of text div related to image than you can go with the `max-height` property of `css`

You can increase and decrease `max-height` property as per your need.

And secondly give `overflow-y: auto` for scroll.

Hope this will helps you.

```css
.second {
 max-height: 165px;
 overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">       
<div class="col-xs-6 first">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 second">
    <p>
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
        Some text lore ipsum etc etc<br />
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Nirav, maybe I understand wrong but I can not use max-height as the image will grow and shrink due to different screen-sizes. I can not fix the height of a responsive column, can I? Even if I choose the maximum height of the image (e.g. 640px) as max-height for the second column, the image could be smaller and the second column still could spread up to 640px.